# What is the purpose of using !! in this situation?

Tags: javascript

see http://webmail.mac.com source.

```
  B.incompatible = !!(B.msie < 7 || B.safari < 500 || B.mozilla < 1.008000999);
  B.unsupported  = !!(B.opera || B.safari < 500) && !B.incompatible;
  B.supported    = !B.incompatible && !B.unsupported;
```

Why are the double "!" used here? Is there any benefit？

Comment: It coerces a value to a Boolean.

Comment: No time to search? Or to look at the top of the "related" list that handily came up whilst you were writing your question, trying to stop you from posting this pointless duplicate?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-operator-in-javascript

Comment: In this case, surely it would be a bool anyway? It's performing || and && on a set of comparison operators.

So the question is still valid. What benefit is it providing *here*?

Comment: Admittedly this q might be more suitable on Code Review, rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: I do not think this is a duplicate? The linked question asks what does the operator do while in this question it asks what the benefit is, which is a good question since most of the time when I see !!, there has been no point of doing it at all.

Comment: @Esailija: I think the problem was the poorly chosen title *What's double “!” mean in JS?* which might have caused some people (including me admittedly) to close the question as duplicate too quickly.

Comment: @FelixKling, should it be retitled and reopened then? I am curious to know if there is a real world situation where there is an actual functional benefit of doing this.

Comment: @Esailija thanks. I just want to know "why".

Comment: @FelixKling can I change my title?

Comment: @Esailija: Probably, but I'm afraid there is not a satisfying answer to this question other  than that it serves no purpose here (which would still be a valid answer). Cynial: You should be able to change your title when you edit your question, but I can do it for you. I voted to reopen anyway.

Comment: @Felix Kling I know and I think "ask first" is a courteous way when the q be closed.

Comment: Actually, there is a really good reason to use the Boolean coercion operator ("!!"). You see the logical AND ("&&") and OR ("||") operators don't explicitly return Boolean values. If the first operand evaluates to true, AND returns the second operand and OR returns the first operand. Opposite for false. Hence they are used as guard and default operators.

Comment: In the aforementioned code, the author explicitly wanted the properties incompatible, unsupported, and supported to be Boolean values. Hence the Boolean coercion operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no point in this case, since the expressions already evaluate to boolean values anyway. It's probably just a programmer being "extra sure".

Comment: Hmm, I missed `B.opera`, but even in that case, the whole expression would still evaluate to a boolean (because of its structure, not because of any language feature that coerces it implicitly).

Comment: yep. IMO, there's rarely a use case for `!!`.  The code in question is probably the worst use of it I've ever seen.

Answer (score 2):

The logical NOT operator ("!") is used to convert true to false and vice versa.

```
! true // expresses false
! false // expresses true
```

However, it also coerces values. Non zero numbers and non empty strings are true. So they become false.

```
! 1.0 // expresses false
! 0.0 // expresses true
! '@' // expresses false
! '' // expresses true
```

Using two NOTs converts it back to the original Boolean value.

```
!! 1.0 // expresses true
!! 0.0 // expresses false
!! '@' // expresses true
!! '' // expresses false
```

It's equivalent to calling the Boolean constructor. However, it's faster (no function call overhead), shorter, and more readable.

```
!! 1.0 === Boolean(1.0) // expresses true
```

Comment: What value is being coerced to a boolean in this situation?

Comment: The general syntax is "!! value" where the variable value will be coerced to a Boolean.

Comment: The expression in the code in the question is already Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Its a very smart way of casting to a bool.

Comment: What's being cast to bool in this situation?